# How to use php mysql with Android for post and get data?

Tags: java, php, android

I want to know how to use php MySql with Android application for get and post the data through android application. I know the JSON Parsing as and when creating database in php with JSON format.But here is creating in MySql.So i don't know how to work with.Can someone help me please.

Here is snap shot of PHP MySql Screen .[image]

Comment: @deepy :- I don't want to create in PHP , I want to use PHP MySql database in my Android App .So thats why posting the question above. OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to the MySQL database you need to have something like a connector.php and it would be good to use a class for writing, reading, updating and deleting the data.
Then call to JSON.

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_entry, "POST", params);

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct connection between Android and MySql & PHP.
In your screen shot you see `phpMyAdmin` this is just a UI for MySQL database (there are more).
To achieve your goal you need a server, for example [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) which contains Apache, MySql & PHP.
With PHP and MySql you need to create a [web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242355/php-web-service-example).
After you create these services you can write an Android application that call these services.

Comment: @ NickF :- I have already made the database and i want to use get and post method through Android.

Comment: as I said you need to create web services

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a webservice which will get the data from your mysql database and send it to your android app.

**First** of all you need a server (Ex: Wamp). WAMP is acronym for Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP, Perl, Python. WAMP software is one click installer which creates an environment for developing PHP, MySQL web application. By installing this software you will be installing Apache, MySQL and PHP

**Second**
Write a php script on your server which can retrieve the required data from the MySQL database. Encode the retrieved data inside a JSON object and send it back to your app.

This tutorial excellently illustrates what you are looking for. Hope it helps.
    URL: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Thanks!