# how to send data in android application to web service once user received successful msg

Tags: android, web-services, http-post

I have message said `successful` in android application once user receives data.

How to write code to send information 'User-key` from android application to web service once user received a successful message. I got stuck on this one. Please help me out, I need HTTP-post code.
I am new to Android..Thanks!!

Comment: refer my answer here URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542767/how-to-use-php-mysql-with-android-for-post-and-get-data/25547529#25547529

Comment: HTTP POST sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4544026/2465777

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, Java: HTTP POST Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request)